# запись в файл через потоки PHP

Tags: php

Меня заинтересовала тема потоков в PHP. Bот например, можно прочитать файл и вывести его в base64:

```
include('php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=file.txt');
```

Подобное можно провернуть и функцией fopen. Можно ли таким образом использовать file_put_contents? Либо же любые другие способы для записи в файл (используя потоки)?

Comment: А разве в документации вот тут http://php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php  в самом низу не написано об этом?

Comment: Написано, но мне интересны варианты записи в файл именно через потоки не вызывая функций для записи.